# Magento: How to get customer group ID from sales/order_item collection?

Tags: magento

How do I get the customer group id from a sales/order_item collection? I realise I may need to traverse back up the sales tree but don't know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I realise I was pretty vague with this question. What I need to do is get the total sales for a product, but only where purchased by a certain customer_group_id. I need to join the orders table to the order_items table to check the customer_group_id, but it's not working for me. This is what I have:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
    ->addExpressionFieldToSelect('ordered','SUM({{qty_ordered}})', array('qty_ordered'=>'qty_ordered'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', '123')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
                       'from' => reverse_date($_REQUEST['startdate']),
                       'to' => reverse_date($_REQUEST['enddate']),
                     ))
    ->join(
        array('orders_table' => $collection->getTable('sales/order')),
        'orders_table.entity_id = main_table.order_id
         AND orders_table.customer_group_id = 1',
        array('customer_group_id'=>'value')
     );
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
'Can't retrieve entity config: sales/sales_flat_order'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the collection you have is of type `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Item_Collection` then you can do the following. Assuming that your collection is `$orderItems`.

```
$order = $orderItems->getSalesOrder();
$customerGroupId = $order->getCustomerGroupId();
```

Comment: Thanks, that would work but I'm grouping by the product to get total sales. Please see my updated question (with more info).

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working. I add the join after the initial "build" of the query like so:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
    ->addExpressionFieldToSelect('ordered','SUM({{qty_ordered}})' , array('qty_ordered'=>'qty_ordered'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('main_table.product_id', $product->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('main_table.created_at', array(
                       'from' => reverse_date($_REQUEST['startdate']),
                       'to' => reverse_date($_REQUEST['enddate']),
                     ));


  $collection->getSelect()->join(
        array('orders_table' => $tableName),
        'orders_table.entity_id = main_table.order_id
         AND (orders_table.customer_group_id = 1 OR orders_table.customer_group_id = 0)'
     );
```

I'm not sure why it works this way and not the other, but hey ho!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using, `$collection->getTable('sales/order')`

use, `'sales_flat_order'`.

So your line would be,

`array('orders_table' => 'sales_flat_order'),`